# How to insert rows from one Snowflake table to another without hardcoding the column names

Tags: insert, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a Snowflake table A as below:

```
CREATE or replace table A
(
    Address VARCHAR(50),
    Zip VARCHAR(50));
    
insert into A (Address, Zip) values
    ('ABC', '20987'),
    ('XYZ', '20989'),
    ('CBZ', '20980');
```

I have an empty Snowflake table B as below

```
CREATE or replace table B
(
    Address VARCHAR(50),
    Zip VARCHAR(50),
    State VARCHAR(50));
```

Now I want to insert rows from Table A to Table B exactly like below

```
insert into B (Address, Zip)
select Address, Zip from A
```

but instead of hardcoding the column names, I want to get it from information_schema as below

```
select COLUMN_NAME 
from db.information_schema.columns 
where table_schema = 'schema' and TABLE_NAME = 'A'
```

Answer (score 2):

Actual code using Snowflake Scripting and parameters. Matching based on column names on target and source. The generated code is executed using `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` and actual statement is returned for debug.

```
DECLARE   
    trg_table_schema    TEXT := 'PUBLIC';
    trg_table_name      TEXT := 'B';
    src_table_schema    TEXT := 'PUBLIC';
    src_table_name      TEXT := 'A';
    sql                 TEXT;
BEGIN  
    WITH trg AS (
        SELECT *
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
        WHERE TABLE_NAME = :trg_table_name
          AND TABLE_SCHEMA = :trg_table_schema
    ), src AS (
        SELECT *
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
        WHERE TABLE_NAME = :src_table_name
          AND TABLE_SCHEMA = :src_table_schema
    )
    SELECT 
        REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(
            'INSERT INTO <trg_table_schema>.<trg_table_name>(<col_list>) 
             SELECT <col_list> FROM <src_table_schema>.<src_table_name>;'
            , '<trg_table_schema>', :trg_table_schema)
            , '<trg_table_name>', :trg_table_name)
            , '<col_list>', LISTAGG(src.COLUMN_NAME, ','))
            , '<src_table_schema>', :src_table_schema)
            , '<src_table_name>', :src_table_name)                             
    INTO :sql
    FROM trg
    JOIN src ON trg.COLUMN_NAME = src.COLUMN_NAME;
      
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE :sql;      
  RETURN :sql;
END;
```

Output:

[image]

The key part is main query which works by taking matching(by name) columns from source and target tables.

```
INSERT INTO <trg_table_schema>.<trg_table_name>(<col_list>) 
SELECT <col_list> FROM <src_table_schema>.<src_table_name>;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using an insert from a select and don't want to list out the column names, just remove the column names and put NULL where there's nothing else to put from the select.

Change this:

```
insert into B (Address, Zip)
select Address, Zip from A
```

To this:

```
insert into B
select Address, Zip, NULL from A
```

If you have a huge number of columns and want a labor-saving approach, the age-old DBA technique of a SQL generator will work fine. Something like this:

```
select 'insert into b select ' || (select listagg(COLUMN_NAME,',') 
           within group (order by ORDINAL_POSITION) COLS
from information_schema.columns
where TABLE_SCHEMA = 'PUBLIC' and TABLE_NAME = 'A') || ' from A;'
;
```

You can then add nulls where required because table B has columns table A does not, or the generator can get more sophisticated and map the columns between the table filling in nulls where a column exists in B but not A.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a stored procedure to generate and execute the INSERT statement.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/stored-procedures-usage.html#stored-procedure-considerations

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/execute-immediate.html

Answer (score 0):

To inserte data in a table of Snowflake from another:

```
INSERT INTO DB_NAME.DB_SCHEMA.DB_TABLE

(FIELD_1, FIELD_2)

SELECT * FROM NSERT INTO DB_NAME.DB_SCHEMA.DB_TABLE WHERE FIELD_1 = 'CONDITION';
```